# XgBoost Script is not outputing binary properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm learning to use `xgboost`, and I have read through the documentation!
However, I'm not understanding why the output of my script is coming out between `0~~2`.
First, I thought it should come as either 0 or 1, since its a `binary` classification, but then, I read it comes as a probability of 0 or 1, however, some outputs are `1.5+` ( at least on the CSV ), which doesnt make sense to me!

I'm unsure if the problem is on `xgboost` parameters or in the csv creation!
This line, `np.expm1(preds)` , im not sure it should be `np.expm1`, but I dont know for what I could change it!

In conclusion, my question is :

**Why the output is not 0 or 1, and instead comes as 0.0xxx and 1.xxx ?**

Here is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('../dataset/train.csv')
train = train.drop('ID', axis=1)

y = train['TARGET']

train = train.drop('TARGET', axis=1)
x = train

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x.as_matrix(), label=y.tolist())

test = pd.read_csv('../dataset/test.csv')

test = test.drop('ID', axis=1)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(test.as_matrix())


# XGBoost params:
def get_params():
    #
    params = {}
    params["objective"] = "binary:logistic"
    params["booster"] = "gbtree"
    params["eval_metric"] = "auc"
    params["eta"] = 0.3  #
    params["subsample"] = 0.50
    params["colsample_bytree"] = 1.0
    params["max_depth"] = 20
    params["nthread"] = 4
    plst = list(params.items())
    #
    return plst


bst = xgb.train(get_params(), dtrain, 1000)

preds = bst.predict(dtest)

print np.max(preds)
print np.min(preds)
print np.average(preds)

# Make Submission
test_aux = pd.read_csv('../dataset/test.csv')
result = pd.DataFrame({"Id": test_aux["ID"], 'TARGET': np.expm1(preds)})

result.to_csv("xgboost_submission.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a `xgb` model with objective `binary:logistic` you get arrays of probabilities for each sample. Those probabilities are the chance of the sample to belong at class `i`.

Let's say you have 3 classes `[A, B, C]`. An output for the sample `y` like `[0.2, 0.6, 0.4]` indicates that this sample will probabliy belong to class **B**.

If you want just the more probable class, take the index of the maximum element in such probability array, for example using `numpy` function [argmax](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

You can find more info at the `xgb` package parameter's [documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md#learning-task-parameters).

Comment: Like this? result = pd.DataFrame({"Id": test_aux["ID"], 'TARGET': np.argmax(preds)})

Comment: Notice `np.argmax` can take an _axis_ argument. If you wan't the label prediction, try with `np.argmax(preds, axis=1)` .

Comment: It didnt work, axis=1 because there is just 1 axis, and when its axis=0, it just fills everything with 66390

Comment: What is the shape of your `preds` variable?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your `preds` array?

Comment: Although i really just need the probability of being 0 or 1.

Comment: I think the question is about probabilities appearing >1, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do that:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

Call **predict** and the output will be 0 or 1, if you call **predict_proba** the output will be probabilities of the classes.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thank you! This didn't exactly answer the original question, but it solved a related problem of mine.