# XGBoost predictions output not binary?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, predict

i'm trying to run a very simple example where XGBoost takes some data and do a binary classification. The [documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md#learning-task-parameters) says that xgboost outputs the probabilities when "binary:logistic" is used

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb

data = np.random.rand(7,10)
label = np.random.randint(2,size=7)
#print data
#print label

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data, label=label)
param = {'bst:max_depth':2, 'bst:eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }
plst = param.items()

bst = xgb.train(plst,dtrain,)

dtest= xgb.DMatrix(np.random.rand(4,10))
ypred = bst.predict(dtest)

print ypred
```

The output is:

```
[ 0.31350434  0.31350434  0.31350434  0.31350434]
```

So what does this output mean? Does it mean that i've a 31 % chance of getting 1?

How do I translate it to 0,1?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826948/xgboost-script-is-not-outputing-binary-properly) seems related, but i cannot get anything useful out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
predictions = [round(value) for value in ypred]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the probability of getting 1.  To get it as a binary value, just check whether it is greater or less than 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the probabilities into an outcome or a class (0 or 1), you can use a threshold, as suggested above (it doesn't necessarily have to be 0.5). The problem lies in finding a Decision Boundary, you can see a good high-level explanation [here](https://blog.clearbrain.com/posts/how-to-predict-yesno-outcomes-using-logistic-regression).

Answer (score 0):

Use `XGBClassifier` instead.

Import it like this:

```py
    from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

This will return 0 or 1 as int for its prediction instead of a float between 0 and 1.

Comment: this is sklearn ...